# PHP + Guzzle, Sending Authorization Key in Header

Tags: php, rest, guzzle

I'm new to Guzzle and I'm attempting to generate the following REST call:

```
https://product-search.api.cj.com/v2/product-search?website-id=1594990&keywords=%2Bsony+-camera

GET /v2/product-search?website-id=1594990&keywords=%2Bsony+-camera HTTP/1.1
Host: link-search.api.cj.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.9.0.8) Gecko/2009032609 Firefox/3.0.8
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive: 300
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: __utma=128446558.2099392322683464700.1239639722.1239639722.1239927095.2; __utmz=128446558.1239639722.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); CONTID=8073; cjuMember=0; JSESSIONID=aM5RSWdqdd_5
Authorization: YOUR DEV KEY HERE

HTTP/1.x 200 OK
Server: Resin/2.1.17
Content-Type: application/xml
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Thu, 26 Apr 2009 10:25:03 GMT
```

I am using the following PHP code:

```
$client = new Client('https://linksearch.api.cj.com', array(
    'id' => $website_id,
    'keywords' => 'sony',
));
$request = $client->get("v2/link-search?website-id={id}&keywords={keywords}");
$request->addHeader('Authorization', $dev_key);
$response = $request->send();
```

The issue here is that with the addHeader() statement I get the response "Bad Request" and without addHeader() I am getting "Unauthorized". It would seem that I am not properly sending my authentication information. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Try avoiding parameters in the uri: {id}, {keywords}. To this day I haven't been able to use them correctly and out of frustration I end up adding them manually like this: $request->getQuery()->add('query', '123'). see guzzlephp.org/http-client/request.html for more info

Comment: - it depends on the versions, the syntax can vary. I recommend those who visit this page use the latest version here http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/index.html , do not be discouraged if it does not work. Just follow the instruction strictly it will work as in my case guzzle6.

Answer (score 2):

The actual issues here were:

1) The header 'authorization' may be case sensitive and may need to be lowercase.

2) A 400 error will be thrown if any of the request parameters are incorrect, even your website-id. A 400 error means "The request was invalid for reasons other than authentication."

Comment: Interesting that the header is case sensitive. I've seen other instances where headers are case sensitive, and all of them ignore the fact that HTTP/1.1 should not care about the casing of a header. However, this is why Guzzle will honor whatever case you supply rather than forcing a specific casing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're creating the $request incorrectly. Try this:

```
$client = new Client();
$request = new Request('POST', 'http://someuri/path/here');
```

Then send the request using $client:

```
$response = $client->send($request);
```