# Google REST-ful call + Guzzle: Setting Authorization Token

Tags: php, curl, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, guzzle

I'm new with Guzzle and I'm trying to make a call to Google API with it. I tried in this way with no luck: [PHP + Guzzle, Sending Authorization Key in Header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15399381/php-guzzle-sending-authorization-key-in-header)

Here is my code:

```
$client = new Client();   
try {
    $request = $client->get ( 'https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga' );

    /*setting Authorization token*/
    $request->addHeader('authorization', $accessToken);

    $query = $request->getQuery();
    $query->set('ids', $profileId);
    $query->set('start-date', $startDate);
    $query->set('end-date', $endDate);
    $query->set('metrics', $metrics);

    $response = $request->send();
    $response = $response->json();
    var_dump($response);

} catch (ClientErrorResponseException $e) {
    var_dump($e->getMessage ());                     
}
```

I'm always getting this response:

```
"Client error response
[status code] 401
[reason phrase] Unauthorized
[url] https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga%3AXXXXXX&start-date=2014-07-01&end-date=2014-07-01&metrics=ga%3Asessions"
```

I've tried the same call using PHP curl and I'm getting the correct response, but I'd like to use Guzzle in this project.

What is the correct way to do this
`array ( CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER =>   array( 'Authorization: Bearer ' . $accessToken ))` with Guzzle?

Comment: Remove the addheader line.  try and add $query->set('oauth_token', $accessToken);

Comment: @DaImTo I've made that change and it worked! Thank you very much. If you mind posting it as an answer... Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you are having is that a Request to the Google Analytics API is sent as a Get.  Adding a header is used for a POST.

```
$request->addHeader('authorization', $accessToken);
```

The following will add the accessToken as part of the Get in your request.

```
$query->set('oauth_token', $accessToken);
```